# Serialization and static variables

Tags: java, serialization, static

i read some articles about serialization/deserialization, but still i cant figure out what happen to static variables during these processes. [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/serialization-in-java/) there is an article, and it provide a code example that i rewrite here:

```
// Java code for serialization and deserialization 
// of a Java object 
import java.io.*; 

class Emp implements Serializable { 
private static final long serialversionUID = 129348938L; 
    transient int a; 
    static int b; 
    String name; 
    int age; 

    // Default constructor 
public Emp(String name, int age, int a, int b) 
    { 
        this.name = name; 
        this.age = age; 
        this.a = a; 
        this.b = b; 
    } 

} 

public class SerialExample { 
public static void printdata(Emp object1) 
    { 
        System.out.println("name = " + object1.name); 
        System.out.println("age = " + object1.age); 
        System.out.println("a = " + object1.a); 
        System.out.println("b = " + object1.b); 
    } 

public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        Emp object = new Emp("ab", 20, 2, 1000); 
        String filename = "shubham.txt"; 

        // Serialization 
        try { 

            // Saving of object in a file 
            FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream (filename); 
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream (file); 

            // Method for serialization of object 
            out.writeObject(object); 

            out.close(); 
            file.close(); 

            System.out.println("Object has been serialized\n"
                            + "Data before Deserialization."); 
            printdata(object); 

            // value of static variable changed 
            object.b = 2000; 
        } 

        catch (IOException ex) { 
            System.out.println("IOException is caught"); 
        } 

        object = null;

        // Deserialization 
        try { 

            // Reading the object from a file 
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream (filename); 
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream (file); 

            // Method for deserialization of object 
            object = (Emp)in.readObject(); 

            in.close(); 
            file.close(); 
            System.out.println("Object has been deserialized\n"
                                + "Data after Deserialization."); 
            printdata(object); 

            // System.out.println("z = " + object1.z); 
        } 

        catch (IOException ex) { 
            System.out.println("IOException is caught"); 
        } 

        catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) { 
            System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException is caught"); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

and output is:

```
Object has been serialized
Data before Deserialization.
name = ab
age = 20
a = 2
b = 1000
Object has been deserialized
Data after Deserialization.
name = ab
age = 20
a = 0
b = 2000
```

in a nutshell, we created an Emp object, we wrote it in a file, then close ObjectOutputStream and FileOutputStream, and **AFTER CLOSING OUTPUTSTREAMS** we changed value of static variable b, and then we set **OBJECT=NULL**, but when we read from file in deserialization process, b has the value we assigned it after writing to file! i mean outputstreams were closed, and original object also was set to null, so how can it be possible that change we apply on b keep either in file or even program fields?!

Comment: Nothing happens to static variables, since they're not part of the state of the object. Static variables are properties of the class, notproperties of the obect. Using `this.b = b;`, although it compiles, is very bad practice. It should be `Emp.b`. And initializing a static variable when an object is being constructed doesn't make much sense. You need to learn about static variables, not about serialization. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html